# Array Sorting Descending Order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm a new programmer to java, been using this website a lot to learn the ways. Today I've stumbled into another problem towards a program I'm doing for practice.

I have an array:

```
    final int EXAMS = 5;
    int[] scores = new int [EXAMS];
```

The values for this array are then asked from the user through a Scanner object:

```
for (int index = 0; index < EXAMS; index++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the score for " + (index+1) +":");
        scores[index] = kb.nextInt();
        if (scores[index] < 0){
            System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.");
            scores[index] = kb.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

I managed to make an ascending order sorting of the values "scores[]":

```
       Arrays.sort(scores);
        System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
        for (int number : scores) 
        {
            System.out.println("Number = "+ number);
        }
```

But I want the sorting to be in descending order. When I put the

`Arrays.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());`

I get an error saying: "no suitable method found for sorting." Please help.

Comment: Sort the Array at the time of insertion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `sort` method in `Arrays` class that accepts an `int[]` and a `Comparator`. The `sort` methods in the `Arrays` class that accept a `Comparator` require an array of reference type (while an `int[]` is an array of a primitive type).

If you change the type of your `scores` array from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, your code will work, since the method `public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` of the `Arrays` class will match your `Arrays.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());` call.

```
final int EXAMS = 5;
Integer[] scores = new Integer [EXAMS]; // the only required change
for (int index = 0; index < EXAMS; index++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the score for " + (index+1) +":");
    scores[index] = kb.nextInt();
    if (scores[index] < 0){
        System.out.println("The number you have entered is invalid.");
        scores[index] = kb.nextInt();
    }
}
Arrays.sort(scores, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
for (int number : scores)  {
    System.out.println("Number = "+ number);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works (using the `Integer` Objects instead of primitive `int`):

```
Integer[] test = {1, 2, 4, 3, 5};
Arrays.sort(test, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test)); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.reverseOrder()
```

Won't work because the array is of primitive type. You can change from int to Integer or try something different like:

```
Arrays.sort(scores);
ArrayUtils.reverse(scores);
```

Your final option would be to make your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your array type from `Primitive type` to `Primitive wrapper class` i.e. `int[] scores = new int [EXAMS]` to `Integer[] scores = new Integer[EXAMS]`

`Arrays.sort` accept wrapper array in the first argument not primitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

does not work with primitives. Try this,

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[]{1,2,3,5,4};
            Arrays.sort(a,Collections.reverseOrder());
            for(int i:a)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sort method for arrays in java.But ArrayList have a sort method.You can the below code to sort the list in reverse order.

```
List l=new ArrayList();
l.add(5);
l.add(1);
l.add(2);
l.add(3);
Collections.sort(l,Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would initialise the values first.

```
// we do 1 to 6 because, 6th iteration is where we going to stop
// so that it will count up to 5.
int[] arr = IntStream.range(1, 6).toArray();
```

then the value of it u pass in the array below.

if we need to sort with primitives int, this would be the approach i would take.

1. sort the list in ascending order
2. reverse all the values

NOTE: this approach would be an N log N time complexity.
of course it will be able to sort faster at N time complexity but
this code is most readable and easy to understand for me.

```java
// this func sorts in n log n time complexity
    public void sortReverse(int[] arr) {
        // 1. now sort all values in descending order
        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length / 2;i++) {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have updated the function to be in camelcase according to java naming convention ;)